# Import-CSV Find How Many Minutes Has Passed

Tags: powershell

I would like to eventually go from csv to html. I have done something similar before, but need to get one step done before the data is ready. I need to get the start time, instead of in time, but in elapsed minutes.

When I bring in the data, one of the columns is formatted like this:

```
mSTART:
2012-08-07 15:58:57.043
2012-08-07 11:00:45.350
2012-08-07 15:54:47.870
2012-08-07 15:44:28.557
```

I would like to manipulate that data into a column that says.

```
Duration:
38 minutes
70 minutes
108 minutes
```

It would be `[(now)-(the start time)]` in minutes.

My current import-csv line looks like this:

```
import-csv .\mydata.csv -header mID, mDES, mTYPE, mVAL, mSTART, mEFF, mDT, mDTDES | Select mDES, mSTART, @{Name="DT";Expression={ $_.mDT+" - "+$_.mDTDES}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn the text in your date column into a date object using the `get-date` commandlet.

Just subtract that result from the current time, which returns a [timespan object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx). If you just want the minutes elapsed, call the `TotalMinutes` property on that object.

```
import-csv .\mydata.csv -header mID, mDES, mTYPE, mVAL, mSTART, mEFF, mDT, mDTDES | 
    Select mDES, mSTART, @{Name="DT";Expression={ $_.mDT+" - "+$_.mDTDES}, @{Name="Duration";Expression={ ((get-date) - (get-date $_.mStart)).TotalMinutes} }
```

Comment: I kept trying to use get-date, but could not get it to work correctly. Will try this out in the AM when I get back to work.

Comment: Well. It kind of works. If I take out the `.minutes`, it works correctly. And it's in a day:hours:minutes format:

    Duration
    2.16:22:18.0439889
    2.21:20:29.7749911  
    2.16:26:27.2559912  
    2.16:36:46.5719913  
    30.21:51:06.7889915 
    169.21:47:58.4969916

If I do the `.minutes`, then it spits out incorrect #s.

    Duration 
    32 
    30 
    36 
    46 
    0 
    57

Comment: @Ty My mistake. It should be TotalMinutes if you want to the total minutes elapsed. See my edit.

Comment: My apologies for not getting back on here sooner. But this worked great. Thank you so much.